# Visualization out of bounds liferay portlet

Tags: javascript, css, liferay

I have a visualization problem when I deploy my web project on liferay portlet. The project is displayed out of the window related to the portlet. No error in the console.

edit:
[Visualization of my portlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7G2.png)
. The problem is that the legend that is showed below the window of the portlet and the title Above (logic visualization of the network) i think that they must be also in that window... If I run the project for example on tomcat, i don't have problems in the visualization.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please add more details?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke sorry, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

There's two options that can lead to this:

- You have CSS that explicitly allows this (I doubt - you'd probably know this)
- You generate unbalanced HTML that messes with the DOM

Your portlet is embedded in the full portal-generated page and better generates proper HTML. Any unbalanced tags like

```
<div>
    something
  </div>
</div> <!-- note: 2 closing divs, only 1 opening -->
```

will mess up the DOM and with it the visualization of your page. When you state that you don't have this problem "when running on tomcat", I'm assuming that you mean that you're running outside of a portal, e.g. as a servlet. A servlet doesn't generate all the "containing" HTML and is typically more forgiving of that kind of HTML.

Comment: I have checked tags and all seems correctly closed. If you want to check , this is the code: [link](http://pastebin.com/5im8XFb9)

Comment: When you're building a portlet and its output, you *must not use* any `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tag. Your output will end up in a HTML document that already has these elements.

Comment: I have tried to do this but the result is the same like in the previous image.

Comment: You might want to try and simplify. There's no way anybody could test your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve